# How to debug application using nodemon in nodeJs

Tags: jquery, node.js, debugging, express, nodemon

We can debug an app in nodeJs using Syntax : `node-debug app.js`
But how can I debug using nodemon
I tried `nodemon --debug app.js` but its not working.
please help me how to debug using nodemon
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio code.
I am using Express generator and OS is windows 8.1

Comment: @mauliksakhare have you found the fix? or any alternatives?

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya I was not able to find any way for it. Please let me know if you find any way for it

Comment: @mauliksakhare , yea I did find the fix. I was a small bug in nodemon version. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800466/nodemon-inspect-debug-not-working/47816378#47816378 for more.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, "--debug" is deprecated, instead use "--inspect".

Simply type: $ nodemon --inspect app.js

You'll see the output like so:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect server.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/26849510-cfac-4aae-8dc0-8d9883809ba5
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector  
Debugger attached...
```

**To open the GUI debugger**, open Chrome browser and type in the URL field:

[ chrome://inspect#devices ]

You'll see at the bottom of the opened page:

```
[  Remote Target
   #LOCALHOST
   Target (v12.18.3)  trace
   app.js
   file:///[your local path of the app.js    ]
   inspect
```

click to **inspect** you'll see the debugger ... enjoy it ...