# Nodemon inspect/debug not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, nodemon

Running `nodemon --inspect index.js` or `nodemon --debug index.js` doesn't work.

**Node Version : 8.9.1**

**Nodemon Version : 1.12.6**

I have tried these with no luck :

- `nodemon --inspect-brk index.js`
- `nodemon -- --inspect index.js`
- `nodemon index.js -- --inspect index.js`
- `nodemon index.js -- --debug index.js`
- `nodemon -- --debug index.js`
- `nodemon --inspect --debug index.js`
- `nodemon --debug-brk index.js`

But `node --inspect index.js` or `node --inspect-brk index.js` works. I wonder how? If any alternatives or some kinda workaround would be great too.

> Please comment if you need further description.

Comment: `nodemon --inspect index.js` works for me.

Comment: @Chris911 which version of `nodemon` and `node` are you on? I have tried `nodemon --inspect index.js` nearly 20 times now. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**SOLVED**,

It seems like `nodemon@1.12.6` was not passing in this argument. There is a newer version available `1.12.7` where everything works fine and well.

Answer source: [Nodemon Issues - Github](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1062#issuecomment-351516144)

Comment: I'm running nodemon 3.0.2 and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 45):

For people coming from search engines, there could be a bug related to nodemon and ts-node.

```
Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --inspect
```

This can be a way to use inspect with nodemon:

```
nodemon --exec 'node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --require ts-node/register src/index.ts'
```

For more information see [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1565#issuecomment-494643872)

Answer (score 14):

```
nodemon --inspect app.js
```

**The .js part is absolutely necessary.**

Answer (score 2):

for anyone who is having error ARG_UNKNOWN_OPTION specially with typescript `ts-nod` and when using auto attach debugger in vscode

example with other arguments like dotenv

`nodemon -r dotenv/config ./src/index.ts -- --inspect`

Answer (score 1):

**FINALLY SOLVED**

Just follow the below steps are you're good to go:

1. Make sure you have updated version of nodemon. Update is using following command: `npm i nodemon@2.0.4 -g`. Make sure to use `-g`(to give nodemon permissions to run as an administrator). If you get some warnings, try running the same with sudo command `sudo npm i nodemon@2.0.4 -g`
2. Then execute the command as: `nodemon --inspect app.js`

**I hope it helped..!!**

Answer (score 0):

As per official doc [Nodemon NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

You can also pass the inspect flag to node through the command line as you would normally:

> nodemon --inspect ./server.js 80

Comment: What is the 80 relating to?

Comment: @JamieHutber 80 is there to specify the port at which inspector will be running.