# Config settings in VS Code Debugger to run docker

Tags: node.js, redis, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

My goal is to set up configuration for my VS Code Debugger.
A legacy code I have is using docker container to run redis, and gulp task runner to launch an app.
My workflow consists of the following commands that I type in terminals:

`docker-compose up` which runs redis with db

`gulp default` starts the app's server

So far I've successfully created config for the gulp task, but still struggling to set up configuration for docker in debugger.

Docker Desktop is installed locally on Windows 10 Pro

`Docker version: 2.0.0.0-win81 (29211)`

docker file: docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 7113:6379
mariadb-test:
    container_name: mariadb-test
    image: wodby/mariadb
    ports:
      - 6604:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_USER=****_****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
      - MYSQL_CHARACTER_SET_FILESYSTEM=utf8mb4
      - MYSQL_CHARACTER_SET_SERVER=utf8mb4
      - MYSQL_CLIENT_DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MYSQL_COLLATION_SERVER=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      - MYSQL_INIT_CONNECT=SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

Gulp task

```
gulp.task('default', function (done) {
    runSequence('build:server', 'watch', 'start');
});

gulp.task('build:server', function (done) {
    var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src(['server/**/*.ts', 'server/**/*.tsx', '!server/test/**/*'])
        .pipe(cache('typescript'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject()).js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.mapSources(function (sourcePath, file) {
            return sourcePath.replace('../../', '../');
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/server'))
        .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['server/**/*.ts', 'server/**/*.tsx', '!server/desktop/**/*', '!server/test/**/*'], ['compile']).on('change', function (e) {
        gutil.log( gutil.colors.blue.bold('[CHANGE] ') +  gutil.colors.green(e.path));
    });
});

gulp.task('start', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'dist/server/bin.js',
        watch: 'dist/',
        ext: 'html js',
        tasks: []
    });
});
```

My launch.json configuration

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Gulp",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
      "args": [
        "default"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Docker",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 6379,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/",
    }
  ]
}
```

All the time I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379).
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't run your appliaction in docker, you don't need to fiddle with that. However, you will need to add `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` to your gulp task when you start your node process.

I would suggest creating a new `debug` task to your gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('debug', function (done) {
  runSequence('build:server', 'watch', 'start:debug');
});

gulp.task('start:debug', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'dist/server/bin.js',
    watch: 'dist/',
    nodeArgs: ['--inspect'] // or --inspect-brk
    ext: 'html js',
    tasks: []
  });
});
```

then you should be able to debug your code using chrome as can be seen here: https://blog.risingstack.com/how-to-debug-a-node-js-app-in-a-docker-container/

Be advised though that according [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800466/nodemon-inspect-debug-not-working#47816378), you should use nodemon 1.12.7 or above to get this working.

Comment: DevTools for Node.js appeared in my Chrome browser after changing args: ['--inspect'] to nodeArgs: ['--inspect']. One step closer.

Comment: Great to hear it's working! I've updated the answer.